# I have to split array data ,make it key value pair and save in a Map

Tags: java, android

I have to split array data ,make it key value pair and save in a map,This is code using for split and save in subdate ,after that in data please clear this

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> subData = new HashMap<String, String>();
CLog.d("",""+fsplit.length);
for (int j = 1; j <=(fsplit.length/3); j++) {
    CLog.d("fsplitsixe", "" + fsplit.length);

           for (String test : fsplit) {
               String s = test;
               String[] parts = s.split("=");
               if (parts.length == 2) {
                   subData.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
               }
           }
    CLog.d("subsizetest",""+subData.size());
    data.put(j, subData);
    CLog.d(TAG, "MAKE_KEY_PAIR" + data);
}
```

My Array Data in fsplit is this :

```
0. url=http://www.krak.dk//53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs
1. datasource=ENIRODK_YELLOW_DATA
2. matchstring=hit-list
3. url=http://www.krak.dk/person/resultat/53504900
4. datasource=ENIRODK_WHITE_DATA
5. matchstring=hit-list
```

excepted output is:

```
MAKE_KEY_PAIR {
    1 = {
        matchstring = hit-list,
        datasource = ENIRODK_YELLOW_DATA,
        url = http://www.krak.dk//53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs
    },
    2 = {
        matchstring = hit-list,
        datasource = ENIRODK_WHITE_DATA,
        url = http://www.krak.dk/person/resultat/53504900
    }
}
```

But my output :

```
MAKE_KEY_PAIR {
    1 = {
        matchstring = hit-list,
        datasource = ENIRODK_WHITE_DATA,
        url = http://www.krak.dk/person/resultat/53504900
    },
    2 = {
        matchstring = hit-list,
        datasource = ENIRODK_WHITE_DATA,
        url = http://www.krak.dk/person/resultat/53504900
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting `fsplit` value

Comment: i didn't make any diff between you expected and actual output.. please update it

Comment: fsplit value0. url=http://www.krak.dk//53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs
1. datasource=ENIRODK_YELLOW_DATA
2. matchstring=hit-list
3. url=http://www.krak.dk/person/resultat/53504900
4. datasource=ENIRODK_WHITE_DATA
5. matchstring=hit-list

Comment: im getting same urls and same datasource

Comment: excepted output means expected output?

Comment: what is the use of `for (int j = 1; j <=(fsplit.length/3); j++) {` this loop??

Comment: j value is use for increment in MAKE_KEY_PAIR{1={},2={},...}-Elite

Comment: did you get all MyArray data in one loop??

Comment: try to declare `Map<String, String> subData = new HashMap<String, String>();` in first for loop..may be it solve your issue.

Comment: Its looping but in subdata only 3 values is thr last three

Comment: change the for loop j to `for (int j = 1; j <=fsplit.length; j++) {`

Comment: i want increment on every 3 loop

Comment: and what is datatype of `fsplit` ..

Comment: try with the answer i provided..it may help you.

Comment: when i tryed to split and save data in subdata, but its not take duplicate key value so im getting only 3 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> subData;
for (int j= 0; j <fsplit.length;) {
    subData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int i=0;
    while(i<3){
        String s = fsplit[j++];
        String[] parts = s.split("=");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            subData.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    data.put(j/3, subData);
}
```

1. `subData` Map has same data:
   As you are using same `subData` Map, existing value is replace with new value, where key is same for both.
2. `data` Map has same data:
   As you are iterating same `fsplit` array multiple time, always last 3 value is get added into `data` map.

Answer (score 0):

### Read the comments too

`foreach` loop Always pick the string content from beginning of the string(fsplit). After getting          first result you are not updating fsplit. 
                fsplit is a `Object` of `String` Class which is immutable. So update the content of fsplit after getting your result 
                at each iteration

```
for (int j = 1; j <=(fsplit.length/3); j++) {
    CLog.d("fsplitsixe", "" + fsplit.length);
    for (String test : fsplit) {  

        /* this line always pick the string content from beginning of the string(fsplit). 
        After gettingfirst result you are not updating fsplit. 
        fsplit is a `Object` of `String` Class which is immutable. 
        So update the content of fsplit after getting your result 
        at each iteration */

        String s = test;
        String[] parts = s.split("=");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
        subData.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}
```